# QGIS Legend multiple name for one shapefile using styles

Tags: qgis, style, legend

I am using styles and presets in QGIS to display the same shapefile on various composers.
The shapefile is representing townships with several fields such as population density, length of water supply pipelines per township, etc.

Each composer is displaying the shapefile with categories based on the fields mentioned above.

I would like to automatically change the name of the shapefile in the legend of the composer by using presets. Is it possible or do I have to manually change the name in each composer?

To do it manually, I use the following feature in Legend options

[image]

In short: I would like to have my layer name "displayed as" XXX for style 1 and YYYY for style 2. This would affect presets, styles and legend.

Comment: If you suceeded it doing it manually, could you add some screenshots of your desired results to totaly clarify what you want to do? I think I got about ~80% of what you are after...

Answer (score 1):

I put a feature request here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19408 which is duplicated with the following request: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17459.

The request is to have a displayed shapefile name depending on selected style, if it works then it would also change the name in the legend I guess.